# Not able to detect Kurento Media Server crash

Tags: kurento

I have implemented kurento server for recording of the live sessions along with WebRTC. I am not able to detect when the server stops recording the sessions as there is no indication of crash as the PID is running but the server is not accepting any streams. I want to understand how to detect that the server is not responding so that using this trigger I can restart the server automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could manage to get this issue sorted out. We had created a very complex architecture where the web video sessions were happening with WebRTC, and the exchange of these feeds were being carried out by Jitsi, and then we had Kurento server running to record these streams in single video. We simplified it by removing Jitsi, and directly using Kurento for flowing the feeds and at the same time recording it. This way the quality of sessions, recording and system improved drastically.

I hope it helps someone looking for similar solutions.